# create two blank row after every row and rearrange the year column from 2001 to 2003

Tags: r, dataframe, encoding

I would like to add two blank rows after every row and rearrange the year column in the order 2001 to 2003.

Initial Data

```
df <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
             var2 = c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'),
             year = c(2001, 2003, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003,2002,2003,2001))
```

Desired output

```
df2 <- data.frame(var1 = c(1,'NA','NA',2,'NA','NA',3,'NA','NA',4,'NA','NA',5,'NA','NA',6,'NA','NA',7,'NA','NA',8,'NA','NA',9),
             var2 = c('a','NA','NA','b','NA','NA','c','NA','NA','d','NA','NA','e','NA','NA','f','NA','NA','g','NA','NA','h','NA','NA','i'),
             year = c(2001,2002,2003,2001,2002, 2003,2001,2002,2003,2001, 2002,2003,2001, 2002, 2003,2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2002,2003,2001,2002,2003))
```

Comment: In your expected `df2` are you sure you expect now 22 to be `8, h, 2003`, and row 25 to be `9, i, 2003`?

Comment: I'd be expecting 27 rows in the output too, not 25. Why are extra rows not added at the end?

Answer (score 2):

This might be an option

```r
> df = df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = 3), ]
> rownames(df) = NULL # cosmetics
> df[-seq(1L, nrow(df), 3), ] = list(rep(NA, 3))
> df$year = rep(sort(unique(df$year)), times = nrow(df) / 3)
> df
   var1 var2 year
1     1    a 2001
2    NA <NA> 2002
3    NA <NA> 2003
4     2    b 2001
5    NA <NA> 2002
6    NA <NA> 2003
7     3    c 2001
8    NA <NA> 2002
9    NA <NA> 2003
10    4    d 2001
11   NA <NA> 2002
12   NA <NA> 2003
13    5    e 2001
14   NA <NA> 2002
15   NA <NA> 2003
16    6    f 2001
17   NA <NA> 2002
18   NA <NA> 2003
19    7    g 2001
20   NA <NA> 2002
21   NA <NA> 2003
22    8    h 2001
23   NA <NA> 2002
24   NA <NA> 2003
25    9    i 2001
26   NA <NA> 2002
27   NA <NA> 2003
```

---

Data:

```r
df = data.frame(var1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),
                var2 = c('a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i'),
                year = c(2001, 2003, 2003, 2001, 2002, 2003,2002,2003,2001))
```